# Why k6 is limiting the number of VUS?

Tags: load-testing, k6

I want to test a REST API which will fetch data from redis cluster. I want to load test the Redis cluster through the REST API. so, when I am trying to load test the REST API using K6, it is not simulating the number of virtual users I mentioned in the k6 command.

`k6 run -d 30s -u 100  ./script.js`

```
import {sleep} from 'k6';

export default function () {
    let stg_url = `some API endpoint`;
    http.get(stg_url);
    sleep(1);
}
```

I intend to test the above URL with 100 VUS at the same time. But K6 uses 14 VUS only.

I dont have memory limitations. My system RAM size is 128GB

[image: less number of VUS]

Comment: No, it uses all 100 VUs (vus_max = 100, max(vus) = 100). 14 VUs was the number of VUs that were active when the test terminated (VUs need to be shut down too)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Thank you @knittl for your valuable input. Now I understand the real meaning of vus and vus_max.

Answer (score 0):

Did you let the test (scenario) run for it's whole duration or did you terminate it before that?

Those 100 VUs are ramped up and reached by the end of the duration (1 minute in your case)